# HTML5 Drag & Drop: Prevent D&D between Browser and Browser-windows

Tags: javascript, angular, html, drag-and-drop

Is there any possibility to disable HTML5 Drag & Drop between browsers/windows?

I'm using an Angular2 application with native HTML5 Drag and Drop and want to prevent users from dragging outside the browser-window and preventing to drop in other windows of the draggable object.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using the material drag and drop added to angular so you can use the element restriction property `cdkDragBoundary` as discussed [in this documentation](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview#restricting-movement-within-an-element)

Comment: He literally tells you he's using the native HTML5 Drag and Drop. How do you assume that it's material drag?